# Modifying a Map

Tags: android, json, dart, flutter

There is a `List<Map<String, dynamic>> httpResponse =[];` need to modify the fetched List to a new List. The List is fetched via Http request and needs to add a key called `all_answer` to modify the requested List and make a  new List `formatedRequest`.

STRUCTURE:-

````
     {
      "category": "History",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "hard",
      "question": "With which Greek philosopher",
      "correct_answer": "Socrates",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Aristotle",
        "Plato",
        "Pythagoras"
      ]
    },
{},
{},
....,
....,
]```
                       need to convert it to
```List<Map<String, dynamic>> formatedRequest =[];```

STRUCTURE:-

```[
     {
      "category": "History",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "hard",
      "question": "With which Greek philosopher",
      "correct_answer": "Socrates",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Aristotle",
        "Plato",
        "Pythagoras"
      ],
      "all_answers":[
        "Aristotle",
        "Plato",
        "Pythagoras",
        "Socrates"

       ]
    },
{},
{},
....,
....,
]```
````